# In jprofiler's jpexport, what probeId to use for a custom pre-loaded probe

Tags: jprofiler

Using Jprofiler's **jpexport** utility, I would like to export events generated by my custom probe. The `-probeId` parameter indicates the probe to export, but it's not clear what probeId should be used.

My case is that of a set of Java classes that implement `InterceptorProbe` and `ProbeProvider`, and loaded at JVM startup using the `-Djprofiler.probeProvider=my.package.MyProvider` JVM parameter. Using `-probeId=1` doesn't seem to work - I get "*The probe with probe ID "1" could not be found in the snapshot*"

Answer (score 1):

After consulting with JProfiler's support I got an answer that works for me - use the probe's full class name.

Suppose I have a profiler class as follows:

```
package my.package;
import com.jprofiler.api.agent.probe.*;

public class MyProbe implements InterceptorProbe {
    ...
}
```

And I want to export events generated by this probe, then I would use:

```
jpexport snapshot.jps ProbeEvents -probeId=my.package.MyProbe events.csv
```